# Update to Android studio 3.0 the Apk size increases

Tags: apk, android-studio-3.0

in the android studio 2.3.3 the apk size 8.9M,but in the android studio 3.0 the apk size is 10.1M.Why this is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends upon the language you used.

Base on this article [Comparing APK sizes](https://android.jlelse.eu/comparing-apk-sizes-a0eb37bb36f):

An app that is created in `Java` which is for example `539 KB` will be `550 KB` in Kotlin. Programming it using React Native will drastically increase the app size to 7 MB. With Flutter.io it will be 7.5 MB.

Also consider the library that you included, that is also one factor that increase the size.